# typescript error: argument type is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, arguments

I am trying to get rid of this erro message and trying to have my code work. My intention is to create an angular form validation consisting of firstName lastName businessName. If firstName and lastName are filled, businessName is no longer required and vice versa. If 'business' segment is selected, onSubmit, we need to clear firstName and lastName. If 'personal' is selected', onSubmit clear 'businessName'. My app.component.html gives this error in StackBlitz environment.

```
Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CustomEvent<any>'.
Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'CustomEvent<any>': detail, initCustomEvent
```

My segment is not in form but it's in the toolbar ion-segment. Here is a snippet and my code. Do I have any structural issues maybe? I can't tell maybe it is too simple. Help me out please.

Edit: Let me also provide you my development environment if it is appropriate [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jwrhqj?file=src%2Fapp.component.html)

```js
//app.component.ts file
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
  AbstractControl,
  ValidationErrors,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./global_styles.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  form!: FormGroup;
  segmentValue = 'personal';

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: [''],
      lastName: [''],
      businessName: [''],
    });

    this.form.setValidators([this.customValidator.bind(this)]);
  }

  customValidator(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    const formGroup = control as FormGroup;
    const firstName = formGroup.get('firstName')!.value;
    const lastName = formGroup.get('lastName')!.value;
    const businessName = formGroup.get('businessName')!.value;

    if (this.segmentValue === 'business' && !businessName) {
      return { businessNameRequired: true };
    }

    if (this.segmentValue === 'personal' && (!firstName || !lastName)) {
      return { namesRequired: true };
    }

    return null;
  }

  segmentChanged(event: CustomEvent) {
    this.segmentValue = event.detail.value;
    this.form.updateValueAndValidity(); // To trigger validation when segment changes
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if (this.segmentValue === 'business') {
      this.form.get('firstName')!.reset();
      this.form.get('lastName')!.reset();
    } else {
      this.form.get('businessName')!.reset();
    }
    // Proceed with form submission
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>

<?-- app.component.html file ?>

<ion-toolbar>
  <ion-segment
    [(ngModel)]="segmentValue"
    (ionChange)="segmentChanged($event as CustomEvent)"
  >
    <ion-segment-button value="business"> Business </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="personal"> Personal </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>
</ion-toolbar>

<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div *ngIf="segmentValue === 'personal'">
    <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstName" formControlName="firstName" />
    <div
      *ngIf="form.hasError('namesRequired') && form.get('firstName').touched"
    >
      First Name is required.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="segmentValue === 'personal'">
    <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lastName" formControlName="lastName" />
    <div *ngIf="form.hasError('namesRequired') && form.get('lastName').touched">
      Last Name is required.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="segmentValue === 'business'">
    <label for="businessName">Business Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="businessName" formControlName="businessName" />
    <div
      *ngIf="
        form.hasError('businessNameRequired') &&
        form.get('businessName').touched
      "
    >
      Business Name is required.
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have typescript `strict` mode enabled in your angular project, then you can't pass `segmentChanged(event: CustomEvent)` because It is not considered valid instance of EventListener.

One way to fix this issue by type assertion

```
segmentChanged(event: Event) {
    this.segmentValue = (event as CustomEvent).detail.value;
    this.form.updateValueAndValidity(); // To trigger validation when segment changes
  }
```